# How do I change the value of a field based on the value of another field in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these documents in my MongoDB

```
_id: ObjectId('64197b3c022b94220a7954e9'),
name: Frank,
gender: male,
_class: com.holdsport.model.person
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64197bd6018930affa3ff88f'),
name: Anna,
gender: female,
_class: com.holdsport.model.person
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64197be3a5c866cb5a93bf3e'),
name: Mary,
gender: female,
_class: com.holdsport.model.person
```

I want to take a script that basically goes through all documents in the database and changes the `_class` based on the gender. If it's a **male** it should change it to `com.holdsport.model.male` and if it's a **female** it should change it to `com.holdsport.model.female`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  gender: {
    $in: [
      "male",
      "female"
    ]
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      _class: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$gender",
              "male"
            ]
          },
          "com.holdsport.model.male",
          "com.holdsport.model.female"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SbtQvlTETso)